# Setting the size of a button and action listener

Tags: java, swing, button, size, setting

Problem 1:

I'm trying to set the size of my button, but doesn't seem to change and instead always fills the entire screen which isn't what I want.

Problem 2:

When I add the  public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e) with my message, it doesn't seem to show up. Maybe it's because of the button filling the entire space up, but I don't really know.

Here is the code for the buttons:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
   public class HockeyGame extends JFrame implements 
      ActionListener, KeyListener, Runnable, WindowListener  //, ActionListener
        {
        Thread t;
        int xpuck, ypuck,xspeed,yspeed,gx,gy,redx2,redy2,lg,rg, redscore, bluescore,
            redx,redy, gx2, gy2, bluex, bluey,bluex2,bluey2,rg2,lg2;
        //int SQUARE_SIZE=10;
        public HockeyGame ( ) {

            }

        public static void main ( String [ ] commandLine ) {
            HockeyGame hg=new HockeyGame();
            hg.init();
        }

        public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"testing");
        }
        public void init() {
            Button b;           
            b = new Button("Click me");
            b.addActionListener(this); 
            b.setSize(40, 40);
            add(b);
            t=new Thread(this);
            this.addKeyListener(this);
            this.setFocusable(true);
            setSize(700,700);
            setVisible ( true );
```

Any help is appreciatedasd

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use common Java nomenclature (i.e. `ypuck` -> `yPuck`) 3) **Don't set the size of buttons.**  Instead, use layouts, padding and layout spacing to put the button where it is needed at the size needed. 4) Use Key Bindings rather than `KeyListener`. 5) Create and alter GUIs on the EDT. 6) `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"testing");` should be `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"testing");` 7) The default layout of a `JFrame` content pane is `BorderLayout`, a component with no constraint is added to `CENTER`

Comment: I agree with all that Andrew posted and will add: read the [layout manager tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) because your problems are due to a lack of understanding as to how they work.

Comment: Also, if you have two different issues, post them as separated questions

Answer (score 2):

Start with simple exercises to make you strong in the basics.

1) Your Button fills up the space because the default layout of your content pane is Border Layout. Set the layout to Flow Layout or any other.

2) The function name should be exactly the same as that defined in Action Listener.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{}
```

None of what I said will make sense until you are strong with the basics.